# How to pass get object pk_ to inside of form valid function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to update an Article. when i try to submit the form i'm getting this error `FileModel.post" must be a "Article" instance` because i need to pass the article(primary key) inside FileModel(post=pk_) for create new files which is related with Article but i don't understand how can i pass the primary key from `get_object` function? I would be grateful for any help.

**VIEWS**

```
class UpdateViews(UpdateView):
    form_class = FileForm
    template_name = 'update.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_object(self):
        pk_ = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        FileModel.objects.filter(post=pk_).delete()
        return get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk_)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            FileModel.objects.create(post=self.get_object.pk_, file=f) # error
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: You can use `self.kwargs.get('pk')` or `form.instance.pk`  in your `form_valid`

Comment: this guy is getting `Cannot assign "68": "FileModel.post" must be a "Article" instance.` error

Comment: You have to use `post_id=form.instance.pk` or `post=form.instance`.

Comment: yeah it's working for me thanks Dear!

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `post_id=form.instance.pk` or `post=form.instance`

So:

```
FileModel.objects.create(post_id=form.instance.pk, file=f)
```

or

```
FileModel.objects.create(post=form.instance, file=f)
```